# summary() produces values but mean() yields NA

Tags: mean, summary

I execute summary() on a variable in a data frame with the following output:

> summary(HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`)
> Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's
> 13158   24101   37990   40272   52564  146830       1
> When I execute mean() or any other function within summary(), the output is:

> mean   (HDIEUR$`Gross national income (GNI) per capita`)
> [1] NA

With all other variables, summary() and mean() work as expected.

Why is this the case?

Comment: You need to provide context.  What language, library, framework is this?  What is the input data?  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask